# Is it possible to install gnome-shell extensions like in Fedora 15?

Tags: gnome, 11.10, extension

I am running the latest Ubuntu 11.10 system up-to-date with `gnome-shell version 3.1.5`

I've tried to install `noally` and `poweroption` extensions to gnome-shell via extracting them to `./local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`

I've restarted the UI and also the comp many times. I've also modified the metadata for the gnome-shell version to 3.1.5 per each extension but no signs of the extension working.

Using the looking glass I found errors which say that it couldn't load each of the extensions because they are not compatible with the version of gnome shell or `gjs`

Answer (score 3):

You have to enable the extensions using [gnome-tweak-tool](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gnome-tweak-tool)[image: Install gnome-tweak-tool].

If you continue to get errors, please remember the the version of GNOME Shell in the repositories is a bit behind because of the fact that this version of Ubuntu is still in development, and not all packages are up to date as yet.